# Spark SQL writing DF to Teradata table using overwrite mode drops table though truncate is True

Tags: teradata, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write the DF records to Teradata table using Spark JDBC.

**Sample code:**

```
df.write.format("jdbc")\
        .option("url", jdbcUrl)\
        .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver") \
        .option("dbtable", dbTableName) \
        .option("user", userName)\
        .option("password", passWord) \
        .option("numPartitions", 3) \
        .option("truncate", True) \
        .mode('overwrite')\
        .save()
```

It is always drop the table and create the table again. When it creates the table again, its creating the table as SET table instead of MULTISET table.

As per Spark documentation, when i pass truncate as True, it should truncate the table instead of drop the table.

> This is a JDBC writer related option. When SaveMode.Overwrite is
>   enabled, this option causes Spark to truncate an existing table
>   instead of dropping and recreating it. This can be more efficient, and
>   prevents the table metadata (e.g., indices) from being removed.
>   However, it will not work in some cases, such as when the new data has
>   a different schema. It defaults to false. This option applies only to
>   writing.

Comment: Try changing your transaction mode to ANSI, the default will then be to create a MULTISET table if SET or MULTISET is not explicitly stated. Secondly, Teradata does not support the `TRUNCATES` statement like other RDBMS. The JDBC driver may interpret the truncate option you are providing as a DROP/CREATE instead.

Comment: @RobPaller: is it possible to mention from Spark program to change the Transaction mode ?

Comment: @RobPaller: or how to explicitly tell spark to create Multiset table?

Comment: For JDBC, it's just a parameter. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_TMODE).  As for dropping the table, I'd remove the `overwrite` option.  From some googling, I think that option drops tables when you're using it with an RDBMS. It's really more intended for Hive.

Answer (score 3):

Default Multiset table can be created in ANSI Mode

you can specify teradata mode with TMODE=ANSI as parameter in the JDBC URL

```
val jdbcUrl = jdbc:teradata://TDHOST/database=databasename,TMODE=ANSI

df.write.format("jdbc")\
        .option("url", jdbcUrl)\
        .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver") \
        .option("dbtable", dbTableName) \
        .option("user", userName)\
        .option("password", passWord) \
        .option("numPartitions", 3) \
        .option("truncate", True) \
        .mode('overwrite')\
        .save()
```